# Do we need to drop index when updating an Enum indexed column

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have a MySQL table that contains a column of type Enum with an index on it.

We wish to update the Enum to add another value. Will we need to drop the the index and create it again?

Comment: it may be faster to just try on dummy table

Comment: No  - although that may depend on the storage engine.  All current index entries will still be valid as you are adding a value.

Comment: @rkosegi Thanks :) I tried on dummy data - adding a new type to the Enum and everything seems okay. But wasn't sure if there are side affects to doing this.

Comment: @RobLambden We use innoDB as engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...`, you can add a new option(s).

If you add them on the *end* of the list, the `ALTER` will be 'instant', regards of table size.  Both the data and the existing index(es) are still valid.

If you rearrange the list in any way, it will trigger an automatic rebuild of the index(es).

Think of it this way:  `ENUM('a', 'b', 'x')` is implemented in a byte where 'a' is represented as `0`, b as 1, x as 2.  Modifying it to `ENUM('a', 'b', 'x', 'z')` is like saying "Now this column might have the number `3` (representing 'z') in it.

If you `JOIN` two tables `ON` the `ENUM`, be aware that the `JOIN` will use the underlying numeric values (0...) for comparison.  So all tables should be `ALTERed` 'simultaneously'.

(This discussion probably applies to all Engines in MySQL/MariaDB, but may not apply to non-MySQL/MariaDB vendors.)